# Is factorial(floor(log(n))) is Big O(n^c) for some constant c?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, logarithm

Can someone explain me whether factorial(floor(log(n))) is Big O(n^c) for some constant c? And, how to prove above answer?

Comment: Your notation is unclear. Do you mean `floor(log(factorial(n)))`? Or `factorial(floor(log(n)))`? Or `floor(factorial(log(n)))`?

Comment: Edited question title accordingly.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you considered/tried already to prove this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about programming

Answer (score 4):

No. [Asymptotically, we have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n)

```
floor(log n)! = Ω(((log n)/3)^log n)
              = Ω(e^(log((log n) / 3)) * log n)
              = Ω(n^(log log n - log 3))
```

And the exponent `log log n - log 3` is obviously not in O(1).